# Disable urlencode in sitemap_generator gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, sitemap

i am using [sitemap_generator](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator) gem and i have a problem with alternates

this is the generating of the sitemap:

```
alternates = [ #adding mobile deep link
      {lang: 'en',
       href: "http://mysite/linker?view=user&user_id=1234"}
  ]

add user_path, :changefreq => 'weekly', :priority => 0.6, :images => user_images, :alternates => alternates
```

but in the sitemap xml file, i get

```
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://mysite/linker?view=user&amp;cat_id=1234"/>
```

so it replaces the `&` with `&amp;`

is there a way to leave it as is? with regular `&` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible - a naked ampersand would be invalid xml. Literal ampersands in xml have to be replaced with `&amp;`

Comment: so its just an xml standard and the link will work fine?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely it.

Comment: btw, but its inside string, not just `&`

Comment: You still need to escape ampersands in attributes